# Remove words from pandas series that are not found in list

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, series

I have a list of strings and a series with sentences for which all punctuation has been removed:

**series** = test_data["reviews']

**words** = [ 'great', 'awesome', 'ok', 'sucky']

I need do remove all words from the series that are not in the list[words]  and assign to new series. 
I did an online search plus tried but unable to find a solution.

Can someone please assist?

Here is what I have:

```
new_series= []
for word in words:
    if  word in significant_words:
         new_series.append(word)
print (new_series)
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Are data like `test_data = pd.DataFrame({'reviews':['great it is', 'ok good well awesome']})` ? Also what is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If data contains sentences and need new columns filled by lists use:

```
words = [ 'great', 'awesome', 'ok', 'sucky'] 
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'reviews':['great it is', 'ok good well awesome']})

words = [ 'great', 'awesome', 'ok', 'sucky'] 

def func(x):
    a, b = [], []
    for word in x.split():
        if word not in words:
            a.append(word)
        else:
            b.append(word)

    return pd.Series([a, b])

test_data[['out','in']]  = test_data["reviews"].apply(func)
print (test_data)
                reviews           out             in
0           great it is      [it, is]        [great]
1  ok good well awesome  [good, well]  [ok, awesome]
```